# Equivalent of DisplayTag for Velocity templating?

Tags: java, jsp, velocity, displaytag

I'm searching for a component that I could plug into a velocity template such as displaytag available for JSP?
I need a table renderer with pagination and autosorting.

Let me know if any idea.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [VelocityTools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view.html), [pager tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/PagerTool.html) and [abstract search tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/AbstractSearchTool.html)

Comment: Other tools provide include a SortTool and a DisplayTool (that can help force content into even-sized cells.

Comment: There is no single tool that does all that DisplayTag does, but all the need functions are available in VelocityTools.